# How do I disable hardware acceleration in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hardware-acceleration

I am using Cubase 5 and currently having problems with Asio Time overload which is not enabling me to produce my work properly. I have tried all the relevant checks with my graphics card (such as unticking all application settings and setting them to a minimum) and the checks Steinberg have sent me (including disabling hyper threading etc.).

The one check I can not able to achieve is the disabling of hardware acceleration as my settings box for this on windows 7 32 bit enterprise is greyed out. I have emailed Foxconn as I have been pointed to it may be a case of settings on my motherboard but had no response and do not have the manual to ensure I have the correct Bios settings, I have also tried to force direct draw emulation to no no avail using the compatability tool kit (although I am not very detailed in computers so I may have set this wrong).

Can anyone help?

The specs are: dual core 3.2 ghz pc with 4gb ddr 2 ram and a 500gb hard drive, windows 7 enterprise audio interface is is with roland ua-1g external soundcard radeon 4350 graphics card and I also have an integrated grapics card ntel (R) 82945g express chipset family graphics card that I need to disable from my mother board which I am unable to.

My Motherboard is Foxconn 9457 md.

Sorry if any of this information is up to

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps:

1. Right click on the desktop and select select `Screen Resolution`
2. On the window that opens up, click on the `Advanced Settings` link
3. Select the `Troubleshoot` tab, then click `Change Settings`
4. Move the Hardware acceleration slider towards `none` to reduce or turn off video hardware acceleration.
   d. Click `OK`, and then click `Restart Now`.

If it is grayed out, I read this on a [forum](http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/131543-disable-hardware-acceleration.html): There is no way to disable hardware acceleration with ATI or Nvidia 's installed. You would have to remove the software and run a generic Windows to disable the acceleration problem.

Answer (score 0):

Press F2 to enter in BIOS (Or any function key). After in AWARD BIOS search ‘Advanced Chipset settings’ . Normally these vt-x/amd-v extension settings will be available in advanced settings in most of the motherboards. Turn off, restart.